# xrdp and tigervnc for Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pam, tigervnc, xrdp

There have been greater changes concerning tigervnc and pam/pambase in the last months. Since then, my setup does not work anymore. Does someone have a guide for setting up xrdp + tigervnc + pam for

Manjaro, 5.8.18-1

xorg-server => 1.20.8-2

[xrdp](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xrdp/)    => 0.9.13.1

[xorgxrdp-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xorgxrdp-git/) => 0.2.13-1

[tigervnc](https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/manjaro/stable/community/x86_64/) => 1.11.0-5

[pam](https://ftp.halifax.rwth-aachen.de/manjaro/stable/core/x86_64/) => 1.4.0

?

Debugging this, I look at following logfiles:

```
/var/log/xrdp.log
/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log 
/var/log/Xorg.X.log
~/.xorgxrdp.X.log
```

but I was not able to get enough information to locate the problem. Are there other relevant files? Are there other components which are involved in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

The problem was not the updates of the listed packages. There was an update of the .xinitrc of [manjaro-xfce-settings](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/profiles-and-settings/manjaro-xfce-settings), see [here](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/profiles-and-settings/manjaro-xfce-settings/-/issues/12) for the solution